# How to make certain page templates visible to admin only

Tags: pages, admin, wp-admin, page-template

Making a site for a client, I have some pages that the client won't be able to edit or delete. These pages rely on specific page templates.

However, I don't want these templates to be available for the client when creating new pages. Is there someway to hide these certain page template from the page attributes dropdown when creating new pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than defining them as custom page templates, you have an alternative.

Use the page specific templates, e.g. for a profile page, with the slug `profile` you could create a `page-profile.php` in your theme, or you can use `page-21.php` where `21` is the ID of that page/post.

Comment: Good interim solution, but too bad so sad if you wanted a `custom_file_name.php`...

Comment: Indeed, though there are methods of removing the need for a post altogether, but I haven't the research to back it up in a comprehensive answer at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not (longer) possible (as the `page_template` filter seems to have been removed with the introduction of the `WP_Theme` class).

The `get_templates_dropdown()` function that calls the templates inside the meta box calls `get_page_templates()` which then has this builder function inside:

```
wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates()
```

And this function comes without any sort of filter or hook.

Comment: So I'm left with manually fetching setting in the DB? Or what are my options?

Comment: You could maybe rebuild that meta box, unregister the original one, register your own, add your changes to the core function and copypaste that into some custom plugin.

Comment: This could not be done in PHP, but as the admin is already full of jQuery, maybe you could just use jQuery to dynamically change the DOM of the admin page, removing one item from the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Simon _"This could not be done in PHP(...)"_ this is **nonsense**.

Comment: @kaiser : could you explain me in a few word why, considering that there is no simple way of doing it with any built-in function, it's perfect nonsense to do it with jQuery - considering this is not a public-wide modification but will only be used in one instance for a particular individual ?

Comment: @kaiser : I would add that I understand that this would not be a _good_ solution, but I see it as a _practical_ & easy solution.

Comment: @Simon I did never say that using Javascript is nonsense. I just said this _could_ be done with PHP and stating the _opposite_ is nonsense. Ad why not JS: A) You can turn it off in your browser B) There're screenreaders - they don't have Javascript C) You can modify it with your browsers developer tools. So using JS or simply CSS (which would be even easier) is not a good idea if you want to lock someone out. It simply won't work in every case. And de-/reregistering the metabox with content built by copypasted core functions isn't that hard. Aside from that, there's Toms solution. ;)